# Subset of sets exrecise in discrete structures course

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

$\{\{b\}\}$ is a subset of $X=\{a,b,\varphi,\{a,b\},\{a,\{b\}\},\{c,\varphi\}\}$: true or false? Can someone explain why is it true/false?

Comment: Do you know the definition of subset?

Comment: I gues that $\varphi$ should rather read $\emptyset$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is every element of $\{\{b\}\}$ an element of $X$?

That is: Is $\{b\}$ an element of $X$?

Well, we do have $b\in X$ and $\{a,b\}\in X$ and $\{b\}\in\{a,\{b\}\}\in X$ and these are all near misses, but we dont't have $\{b\}\in X$.
Unless it happens that $a$ equals $\{b\}$, that is.

Comment: Or it happens that $\varphi = \{b\}$, or $a=b$, or $c = \varphi = b$.  (I guess if $\varphi$ is supposed to be $\emptyset$ then the first one is impossible.)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\;\{\{b\}\}\;$ is a subset of $\;X\;$ iff $\;\{b\}\;$ is an element of $\;X\;$ . Is it?

Answer (score 1):

$\{\{b\}\}$ is a set with only one element namely $\{b\}$  and all subsets of $X$ with one element are:

$\{a\}$

$\{b\}$

$\{\emptyset\}$

$\{\{a,b\}\}$

$\{\{a,\{b\}\}\}$

$\{\{c,\emptyset\}\}$

So $\{\{b\}\}$ **is not** element of $X$.

Comment: Good points Adi :+)